# Indeterminate Progress bar not displayed in Mahapps when using DialogCoordinator

Tags: c#, progress-bar, mahapps.metro

When I try to call the mahapps progress dialog from ViewModel:

```
public async void Test()
{
    var controller =
        await
        this.dialogCoordinator.ShowProgressAsync(
            this, 
            "Progress from VM", 
            "Progressing all the things, wait 3 seconds");
    controller.SetIndeterminate();

    // await Task.Delay(3000);

    // await controller.CloseAsync();            
}
```

the Dialog is shown but the rolling indeterminate progress is not displayed in the bottom of the dialog. Using Snoop to spy for the XAML shows that the control is there but the bar does not display the rolling balls. Any Ideas?

Comment: Which version of MahApps do you use?

Comment: I use version 1.2.4. and was able to spot the problem. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the issue. I just missed one line when adding the styles:

```
<ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Controls.xaml" />
<ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Fonts.xaml" />
<ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Colors.xaml" />
<ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/Baselight.xaml" />

<!-- missed the inclusion of accent color style, have own style for anything else so I didn't noticed that -->
<ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/Blue.xaml" />

<ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Clean/Clean.xaml"/>
```